# How to configure swap slot feature? Currently after deployment still i am seeing old version of web app

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a staging slot (which has different url than dev app service) for our dev environment.

Than I have enabled Auto Swap Slot feature for staging app service/slot in Application settings as:

[image]

The same settings is not enabled for Dev App Service.

Then in VSTS I have added **deploy azure app service** task  with Swap feature enabled . This will deploy new version to slot:

[image]

Then I have added a swap slot task which will swap Stage with DEV/PROD:

[image]

But after deployment when i access DEV site url still I see old
changes and not published one.

What configuration i am missing here?

Comment: You have auto swap in Azure + a manual swap in VSTS?

Comment: @juunas so do i need off one of the configuration ?

Comment: Auto SWAP feature is on for slot app service and not for Prod App Service

Comment: Turn off the auto-swap if you do it from VSTS

Comment: @JoeyCai what exactly you are asking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As junnas said, **turn off the auto-swap** and only slot swap manually then the above steps you provided are all right.

The staging and production slots will then be swapped over, leaving the old production version in the staging app and the latest version in the production slot.**This flow supports the actual slot swaps being automated, but with manual approval.**

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukhybridcloud/2018/03/19/azure-devops-automate-app-service-slot-swaps-in-your-vsts-release-pipeline/).